# Abstract away the DAL from Entity Framework implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, data-access-layer, abstraction

First of all I'm sorry if this is going to be a long post, but I don't know how to explain the problem in the correct way without the required details.

I'm having troubles finding a way to abstract my DAL from an Entity Framework implementation. The project I'm working on is very small, but if in future I'd want to switch to another ORM like NHibernate, or just plain ADO.NET, I'd like to write code just for the implementation, not the entire DAL.

Say I have these entities in my MyWallet.DAL:

```
public interface IWallet {
    long Id { get; set; }
    float TotalAmountOfMoney { get; set; }
    long CurrencyId { get; set; }
    ICurrency Currency { get; set; }
    DateTime RecordedOn { get; set; }
    ICollection<IMoneyMovement> MoneyMovements { get; set; }
}

public interface ICurrency {
    long Id { get; set; }
    char Symbol { get; set; }
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public interface IMoneyMovement {
    long Id { get; set; }
    float Amount { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    long WalletId { get; set; }
    IWallet Wallet { get; set; }
    DateTime RecordedOn { get; set; }
    DateTime MovedOn { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see these are plain interfaces which I plan to implement on another library which will contain the actual Entity Framework implementation (say MyWallet.DAL.EntityFramework). Of course I'm going to decorate the entities implementation with Entity Framework specific attributes as [Key] or [ForeignKey] and stuff like that.

I also defined some repository in MyWallet.DAL like IWalletRepository, IMoneyMovementRepository, ICurrencyRepository to gain access to the entities. Actually I don't know if this is the right way to design access to the entities. Of course I also defined factories to get the concrete implementation of the entities.

In my business layer I defined services to handle the object request, work with the DAL entities and return a business object, like this:

```
public class WalletService {
    private readonly IWalletRepository _walletRepository;
    private readonly IWalletFactory _walletFactory;

    public WalletService(IWalletRepository walletRepository, 
        IWalletFactory walletFactory) {

        _walletRepository = walletRepository;
        _walletFactory = walletFactory;
    }

    public CreatedWallet CreateWallet(CreateWalletRequest request) {
        var wallet = _walletFactory.Create();

        wallet.CurrencyId = request.CurrencyId;
        wallet.TotalAmountOfMoney = request.TotalAmountOfMoney;
        wallet.RecordedOn = DateTime.Now;

        _walletRepository.Create(wallet);
        _walletRepository.SaveChanges();

        return new CreatedWallet {
            Id = wallet.Id
        }
    }
}
```

I thought this was going to work seamlessly, or at worst - in a situation when I've got more than one repository - I could share the DataContext so I'd need to fire the SaveChanges method on just one to reflect the changes on the database.

The problem is with the repository implementation, in this case I'll continue with Entity Framework:

```
public class EFDataContext : DbContext {
    public EFDataContext() : base ("name=MyConnectionString") {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<EFWallet> Wallets { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EFMoneyMovement> MoneyMovements { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EFCurrency> Currencies { get; set; }
}

public class EFWalletRepository : IWalletRepository {
    private readonly EFDbContext _dataContext;

    public EFWalletRepository(EFDbContext dataContext) {
        _dataContext = dataContext ?? new EFDbContext();
    }

    public int SaveChanges() {
        return _dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        _dataContext.Dispose();
    }

    public void Create(IWallet wallet) {
        ...???
    }
}
```

Now that's the problem: how do I work with interfaces when the DataContext knows only about concrete implementations? Am I doing this all wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Ok so, basically, as stated out by @TomTom, why fight Entity Framework when you could just embrace its power? I guess I'll just let EF be the abstraction. In fact, by letting EF act as the DAL, you can just focus on the business logic of your project.

And to put it all together and respond to @tdragon regarding the repositories / unit of work issue: yes, I could either wrap multiple repositories inside an unit of work or simply let the DbContext be the unit of work:

```
public class EFWalletRepository : IWalletRepository {
    private readonly EFDbContext _dataContext;

    public EFWalletRepository() {
        _dataContext = new EFDbContext();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        _dataContext.Dispose();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Wallet> Wallets {
        get { return _dataContext.Wallets; }
    }

    public void SaveWallet(Wallet wallet) {
        if (wallet.Id == 0) {
            _dataContext.Wallets.Add(wallet);
        } else {
            var databaseEntry = _dataContext.Wallets.Find(wallet.Id);
            //update properties
        }

        _dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are also abstracting data; you should only abstract logic. Keep the POCO's in the business layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply speaking: yes, you do it wrong. You introduce a bad abstraction (that costs you dearly in functionality) "because of". EF already is an abstraction.

Any abstraction on top of it will cost you in terms of functionality used - which in terms of databases comes with a big performance impact. Want an example? "Include" to preload navigation properties (instead of lazy loading). You will have to work around this and a lot of more detailed behavior that is ORM specific - for the gain of having what? And if you give up on those higher more specific functions your performance WILL suffer.

Comment: I think it just depends on his requirements. I wouldn't cover these features till I need them YAGNI. The primary question is where is the biggest business value behind ? Having an easier way to change the dbms or having an easier open window to the EF features.

EF is only a "halfway" abstraction as it is strongly relied to the EF Technology itself. this is not bad by default but it is an dependency. I think both ways are possible and should be validated against the requirements

Comment: I don't see it this way. in my case I never needed this EF feature and most propably i will never need them.If this features ARE obvious your right. but are they really in his case? But your rude post feels little strange and not very professional for me.... It is very bad to implement everything just to fear "maybe in 10 years I may need it" . If you know you *will* need it, then implement it. But without knowing his context you can't know. it would be better  to advise him to think about wether it is very likely he will need this feature or to ask the businessman !

Comment: Ok, maybe I should have stated it before, but this project I'm working on is just "homework", just a way to improve design skills by building up something from a very small starting point. Of course this project doesn't need at all this kind of abstraction, moreover in this case where EF is an abstraction per se, even if not in the way I picture an abstraction to be.

Comment: @BoasEnkler Well, Boas, that is very likely an example of incompetence because somehow I use this particular feature pretty much in more than 50% of my queries. So, either I work in VERY complicated queries only, or you basically fall into the trap I have seen in TON of project teams: people not knowing what they do and then being astonished once someone shows them proper performance. There seem to be a LOT of baseline features you just never use. Well, nice for you. Some of us HAVE to work professionally because the application demands it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason to abstract your model (entities). Do you expect them to change when you change the way you access your database?

But if you want to keep it that way, you can make your repository interfaces generic, and pass the concrete entity type when defining repository, so you would end up with:

```
public class EFWalletRepository : IWalletRepository<EFWallet>
{
    public void Create(EFWallet wallet)
    {
        _dataContext.Add(wallet);
    }
}
```

Other suggestions:

1. You should not expose sets for your model properties. It's against OOP rules - you should rather expose some methods to manipulate the objects, the state should be more internal.
2. You probably should not add `SaveChanges()` method to your repository - this should be a "unit of work" job to commit all changes to the database.
3. You would face a problem when you would use more than one repository in your service layer, as you create a new `DbContext` for repository, when you should have one for single "unit of work".

Comment: I'm abstracting entities because EF has got its own decorators, which I didn't want to include in my DAL library.
`[Table("wallet")]
    public class Wallet {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        ....
    }`

Comment: Instead of using attributes to decorate your entities, you could use configuration files. Then, you entities would stay EF-free and clean, see here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx